# switching between v-if and v-else with a button

Tags: javascript, vue.js

am having problem switching from the first section(v-if) to the second second(v-else) section using v-if. as default now section(v-if) is displaying and i created a button(startGame) to change to the second section(v-else) when clicked but i find it not easy to do please help me out

```
<section class="row controls" v-if="!gameIsrunning">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
          <button id="start-game" @click="startGame">START NEW GAME</button>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="row controls" v-else>
        <div class="small-12 columns">
          <button id="attack">ATTACK</button>
          <button id="special-attack">SPECIAL ATTACK</button>
          <button id="heal">HEAL</button>
          <button id="give-up">GIVE UP</button>
        </div>
      </section>
  <script>
      let app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
          playerHealth: 100,
          monsterHealth: 100,
          gameIsRunning: false
        },
        methods: {
          startGame: function() {
            this.gameIsRunning = true;
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: `v-if` removes the element DOM completely, so after the first click, your code will not work at all as the button `start-game` is not there at all.

Comment: looks fine to me, do you get any errors in console?

Comment: You have a typo. Your variable is called `gameIsRunning` but at the `v-if` you called it `gameIsrunning`